# Ionic 2 : TranslateService doesn't work at initial load when triggered from constructor

Tags: ionic-framework

In **app.component.ts** constructor, after platform is ready, i am using Cordova Globalization to get the current preferred locale language in the mobile and at the same time i am also calling a TranslateService to translate the text.

Well in Logic.ts i am calling a local function to translate the text, and that text i will use in loading controller to show the 'Authenticate' as text when the user hits the login button.

The problem is in the initial load the translate doesn't work, but when you logout and come back to same login page **the translate works**. What i think is the translate is loaded but it is not reflected and so the reason you are not able to see it in UI, but when you reenter the same page you will see the translation is working properly.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Globalization } from '@ionic-native/globalization';

import { LoginPage } from '../pages/login/login';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
  rootPage:any = LoginPage;
 i18nObj: any = {};

  constructor(
    platform: Platform, 
    statusBar: StatusBar, 
    public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private translateService: TranslateService,
    private globalization: Globalization) {

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();

      // To initialize English as our default language 
      this.translateService.setDefaultLang('en');
      this.translateService.use('en');

      this.globalization.getPreferredLanguage()
        .then(result => {
          // To check and convert language into code
          let languageCode = this.getSuitableLanguage(result.value);

          // To set locale language          
          this.translateService.setDefaultLang(languageCode);
          this.translateService.use(languageCode);
        })
        .catch(e => {
          let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: this.i18nObj.alert_error,
            subTitle: e,
            buttons: [this.i18nObj.alert_btn_OK]
          });
          alert.present();
        });
    });

    this.convertText();
  }

  convertText () {
    this.translateService.get('Alert.btn_OK').subscribe(t => {
      this.i18nObj.alert_btn_OK = t;
    });
    this.translateService.get('Alert.error').subscribe(t => {
      this.i18nObj.alert_error = t;
    });
  }

  getSuitableLanguage(languageCode) {
    let langCode = languageCode.substring(0, 2).toLowerCase();

    switch(langCode){
      case 'en' : {
        return 'en';
      }
      case 'fr' : {
        return 'fr';
      }
      default : {
        return 'en';
      }
    }
  }

}
```

**login.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, LoadingController, Events, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { AuthenticationProvider } from '../../providers/authentication/authentication';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html',
})
export class LoginPage {

  usercreds: any;
  loader: any;
  service: any;
  i18nObj: any = {};

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public loginCtrl: LoadingController,
    public events: Events,
    public authService: AuthenticationProvider, 
    public alertCtrl: AlertController,
    private translateService: TranslateService) {
    this.usercreds = {
      name: '',
      password: ''
    }
    this.service= authService;

    this.convertText();
  }

  login(user) {
    if((user.password !== "") || (user.name !== "") ){
      this.loader = this.loginCtrl.create({
        content: this.i18nObj.alert_logginIn
      });
      this.loader.present();

      this.service.authLogIn(user).then(data => {
        // ....logic to check and response and nav To home page

        this.clearLoginFields();                                          // To clear login fields
      });
    } else {
      let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: this.i18nObj.alert_userAndPassEmpty,
        subTitle: this.i18nObj.alert_userAndPassEmpty_subtitle,
        buttons: ['OK']
      });
      alert.present();
      this.clearLoginFields();
    }
  }

  private clearLoginFields() {
    this.usercreds.name = "";
    this.usercreds.password = "";
  }

  convertText () {
    this.translateService.get('Alert.logginIn').subscribe(t => {
      this.i18nObj.alert_logginIn = t;
    });
    this.translateService.get('Alert.userAndPassEmpty').subscribe(t => {
      this.i18nObj.alert_userAndPassEmpty = t;
    });
    this.translateService.get('Alert.userAndPassEmpty_subtitle').subscribe(t => {
      this.i18nObj.alert_userAndPassEmpty_subtitle = t;
    });
  }

}
```

en.json

```
{
    "Alert" : {
        "logginIn" : "Logging in",
        "userAndPassEmpty" : "User and Password fields cannot be empty",
        "userAndPassEmpty_subtitle" : "Please try again",
        "btn_OK" : "OK",
        "error" : "Error"
    }
}
```

Result : At Initial load

[image]

After revisiting the same view

[image]

Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong ? What correction do i have to make in my code so that the translation will work's in **ts** files at the initial view load also.

Comment: You will have to ensure the alert gets loaded after convertText returns value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added delay of 5sec on the initial page and then the translation worked for me. Due to asynchronous call for translation, i was not getting translated text due to which it was showing the key instead of text.